# AlertDialog style changes

Tags: java, android, alert, android-alertdialog

I'm making an app where an AlertDialog is needed. When the dialog opens, it looks like a Jellybean alert dialog, but when I paste the code in another project it looks like a Lollipop alert dialog. Why?
(I'm making the dialog using AlertDialog.Builder solution; said in case another solution exists. Also, I'm programming with AIDE development environment and I have Lollipop OS installed on the device.)

Comment: just change your application compile level. if compileSdkVersion 23 then it's working fine for all the version's of Android.

Answer (score 0):

make custom alert dialog

```
check this reference:
```

[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

if use AppCompact style

you can add this line to it

```
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatAlertDialogStyle</item>
```

and in your code 
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder =
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

setContentView property can use your custom layout

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
```